# Как узнать какие потоки данных используются в чужой программе (srcds)

Tags: c

моя программа должна прочитать данные из другой программы (srcds). Но при перенаправлении потока вывода `srcds`, ничего не происходит, на стеке написали: Если вывод программы srcds нельзя перенаправить с помощью ">", то дело плохо. Это значит, что вывод сделан не через stdio а через что-то другое, например `conio`. Тогда только парсить вывод на экран, но это дело не одного вечера.

Что мне делать? Насколько я знаю, есть всего три стандартных потока данных, как я узнаю что за инопланетные потоки данных используются в `srcds`? Мне нужно прочитать вывод программы `srcds`

Comment: `stderr` уже проверил? может оно туда всё пишет? «работа через `conio`» подразумевает приямую работу с терминалом, а не с каким-то потоком... для *nix-систем можно было бы предоставить псевдотерминал приложению и уже с ним работать.... на win — не уверен, что такое там принципиально возможно...

Comment: ЗЫ: если `srcds` — это `Source Dedicated Server`, то он почти наверняка просто пишет все свои логи в `stderr`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, извиняюсь за игнор длинною в 5 часов. Проверил stderr, в файле оказалось только 9 строк, значит логи через stderr не выводятся. Знаю только что srcds это сервер по КС го. Но это не мой сервер и я к нему практически никакого отношения не имею. За ответы большое спасибо вам:)